# Data tables MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm not well parsed in Python since I'm trying to translate this MATLAB code which basically goes line by line analyzing big data tables to python with little to no success. So far I have been able to import the excel data sheet to python and little to no succes in assigning the new values of the array after the second if in python.

```
    clear all; clc;

T=input('Ingrese el numero de filas en el BOM: ');
asig=sprintf('A1:AU%g',T); %Asign arrays to analyze

%Data transfer from excel
[num,BOM,raw]=xlsread('HRS','BOM',asig);
c=47; %columns to analyze
k=0;

%Clean of Product Definition
for i=1:1:T
    mk=strcmp(BOM(i,2),'Product Definition');
    while mk ~= 1 
        k=k + 1;
        for j=1:1:c
            BOM_NPD(k,j)=BOM(i,j);
        end
        mk=1;
    end
end
```

In Python

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


#Obtencion de tabla de archivo excel 
BOM_aslist = pd.read_excel(r'')
BOM = np.array(BOM_aslist)

T=len(BOM)

c=10 #Numero de Columnas
k=-1; x=0; l=0
BOM_NPD=np.zeros((736,c))

#Clean of "Product Definition"

for i in range(1,T):
    BOM_NPD = BOM_NPD.copy()
    #print (BOM[i,1])
    if BOM[i,1] == 'Product Definition':
        l+=1
    else:
        if l==1:
            k=0;
        k+=1
        for j in range(0,c):
            x+=1
            #print(BOM[i,j])
            BOM_NPD[k,j]=BOM[i,j]

print (BOM_NPD)
```

I'm basically getting this: could not convert string to float: 'Work Instructions'

Comment: you need to provide more detail. 1. which line of code has issue 2. it seems you did try to convert one of  col title to float

Comment: Also, from the code provided, the ```BOM_aslist = pd.read_excel(r'')``` line should throw an error,?  pd_read_csv requires as a minimum a url parameter, file file path for which r'' doesn't satisfy this need.  The result of this command should be a pandas Data frame, so I would also like to understand why the need to convert to an np.array?

Comment: @itprorh66  didn't add anything here 'cause it's my full directory, but the error seems to be at BOM_NPD[k,j]=BOM[i,j]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your problem is not reproducible without the data you are reading from the excel file. Please read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953). Please also take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error is clear, "could not convert string to float"

I think the error is due to these lines, I've added some comments

```
BOM_NPD=np.zeros((736,c)) # BOM_NPD is initialized as a numpy float array

#Clean of "Product Definition"

for i in range(1,T):
    BOM_NPD = BOM_NPD.copy() 
    #print (BOM[i,1])
    if BOM[i,1] == 'Product Definition':
        l+=1
    else:
        if l==1:
            k=0;
        k+=1
        for j in range(0,c):
            x+=1
            #print(BOM[i,j])
            BOM_NPD[k,j]=BOM[i,j] # Here is the problem, maybe your BOM[i, j] is a string, so you can't put a string into a float element
```

Also, the code is not very clear, try to provide more details

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


#Obtencion de tabla de archivo excel 
BOM_aslist = pd.read_excel(r'')
BOM = np.array(BOM_aslist)

T=len(BOM)

c=10 #Numero de Columnas
k=-1; x=0; l=0
BOM_NPD=pd.DataFrame(index=range(736),columns=range(c))

#Clean of "Product Definition"

for i in range(1,T):
    #print (BOM[i,1])
    if BOM[i,1] == 'Product Definition':
        l+=1
    else:
        if l==1:
            k=0;
        k+=1
        for j in range(0,c):
            x+=1
            #print(BOM[i,j])
            BOM_NPD.iloc[k,j]=BOM[i,j]

print (BOM_NPD)
```

Comment: What the MATLAB code does is go line by line reading the column where it finds 'Product Definition' if it finds it  wont write that line. This MATLAB code is pretty much a clean up code for big excel files with several types of data (int, float, str) in Matlab it works flawlessly but I'm struggling with Python.

Comment: So try to use "pandas" in python, not the numpy.

Comment: Do you know any website with Pandas info that would allow me to do the "for" loop? Thanks.

Comment: I have changed your codes, try with this, perhaps that will be better

Comment: It works now, Thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear that, consider to accept my answer